# Springboot with saml2 sso: No relying party registration found

Tags: spring-boot, saml-2.0, okta

I have a simple Springboot 3.1.2 application with SAML2 using okta as an Identity Provider.

My security config is:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, SuezGebruikersService suezGebruikersService) throws Exception {
    OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setResponseAuthenticationConverter((Converter<ResponseToken, Saml2Authentication>) responseToken -> {
        Assertion assertion = CollectionUtils.firstElement(responseToken.getResponse().getAssertions());
        Map<String, List<Object>> attributes = getAssertionAttributes(assertion);
        int cprid = -1;
        if (attributes.get("cprid") != null && attributes.get("cprid").size() == 1) {
            cprid = Integer.parseInt((String) attributes.get("cprid").get(0));
        }
        SuezGebruiker principal = (SuezGebruiker) suezGebruikersService.getUserRights(cprid, attributes);
        return new Saml2Authentication(principal, responseToken.getToken().getSaml2Response(), principal.getAuthorities());
    });

    authenticationProvider.setAssertionValidator(OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.createDefaultAssertionValidator());

    DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver relyingPartyRegistrationResolver = new DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver(this.relyingPartyRegistrationRepository);
    Saml2MetadataFilter filter = new Saml2MetadataFilter(relyingPartyRegistrationResolver, new OpenSamlMetadataResolver());

    return http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .saml2Login((saml2 -> saml2.authenticationManager(new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider))))
            .saml2Logout(withDefaults())
            .addFilterBefore(filter, Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(switchUserFilter(suezGebruikersService), AuthorizationFilter.class)
            .build();
}
```

After login at okta and returning back to the Service Provider I get:

```
No relying party registration found
```

I have no idea what is causing the error.

Is it in my okta configuration or in my Springboot application?

Can anybody give me a hint where to start?